# t sql union vs join order (efficiency)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a relatively simple question.

I have dataset A and dataset B, both identical in structure.

The end result is going to be a union all of dataset A and dataset B, we'll call it dataset C.

But before the final version, the end dataset needs to be filtered by joining on dataset X.

The question is should I join dataset A on dataset X, join dataset B on dataset X, and THEN union ALL A and B, or should I UNION ALL A and B into C, then join C on X.

What is faster, more memory efficient, etc?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you just tried it and compared the execution times and query plans in SSMS?

Comment: WHy do you think anyone here is in a better position to tell you which is more efficient for your queries, against your data, on your hardware, than you are?

Comment: The point isn't what will be more efficient for this particular dataset on this particular server in this particular query, I was asking if one order is more efficient for large datasets in terms of the way sql processes code. If there is no universal answer and it is slower or faster on a case by case basis when using similar size datasets than there is something wrong with the way sql server is coded.

Comment: `If there is no universal answer...than (sic) there is something wrong with the way sql server is coded` I think there is seomthing wrong with your understanding of database systems. Or SQL Server in particular.

Comment: If X is a special event table with good indexes into A & B (largish tables), with good statistics, SQL Server will perform the JOIN first **even if** you expressed the UNION ALL in a derived table. If you have two small tables A & B with good intersection, and a largish X table, the UNION/SORT will occur before the JOIN, again given good statistics. Apart from these extremes, anything goes.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on so many things, it's impossible to say from your question: Indexing, Statistics, INNER or OUTER JOIN, data types.  You'd have to know a lot more and even then you really would need to compare the execution plans.

Because I don't like to repeat myself, I would probably do the JOIN outside the UNION for maintenance reasons, but if I had to bet, I'd probably bet the join first can outperform it - especially if the join cuts down on the number of rows drastically.

Comment: They are all inner joins. They won't always cut down the row count drastically. I just ran a few test scenarios with the following results:

performing the joins on each dataset, and then unioning all after averaged around 26 seconds to complete.

performing the union all first, then joining the result resulted in an average of 21.5 seconds.

This is with a result of ~65k rows. That seems a significant difference for this low amount of rows.

Comment: @jz3 I'd have to see more about the data, the code and the execution plans to say anything more.

Answer (score 1):

My gut feel would be join both to x then union the results. That way the sql server optimiser has better chance of providing an optimal query plan but this may be a case where you write both, check the execution plans and timings to really see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

I would really look to see the execution plan of both and see what takes less time/resources.

[Here is a great starter video](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/06/13/sql-server-video-beginning-performance-tuning-with-sql-server-execution-plan/) on getting started with performance tuning on SQL Authority.  A topic that really never gets enough attention.

Monitoring the execution plan over the evolution of your optimizations is a great technique as it really gets down in the trenches to show you if and how further indexes and other tuning techniques pay off in your execution.